# keep certain values in a dictionary values based on list

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d`

```
 d = {'1': ['Fisherman', 'fam', '125', '53901', 'funny'],
     '2': ['Joi', '521', 'funny','fun', '1245']}
```

and a list `l`

```
l = ['521', 'Fisherman', 'fun','A2ML1', 'A3GALT2','funny']
```

I want to keep values in `d` that are not in `l`. I want my output to be

```
d_list = {'1': ['fam','125', '53901'],'2': ['Joi', '1245']}
```

To do so, I tried this

```
d_list = [] 
for k, v in d.items():
    if v not in l:
        d_list.append(v)
```

But this doesn't give me what I want. What can I do to my code (or new code) to get my desired `d_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v` is a list not a str

try this code:

```
d1 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    d1[k] = [i for i in v if i not in l]
d1
```

output:

```
{'1': ['fam', '125', '53901'], '2': ['Joi', '1245']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can doe it like this also

```py
{key:set(values) - set(l) for key, values in d.items()}
```

or if you want values to be list instead of set

```py
{key:list(set(values) - set(l)) for key, values in d.items()}
```